# Execute javascript after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I use some Jquery/ajax code to refresh the content of a div according to the value of a select. So i have this:

```
<select id="agence" name="agence" class="selectpicker scrollMe " data-style="btn-default" onchange="getContent('divmailsav')">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<div id="divmailsav">
    <?php include 'formmail.php'; ?>
</div>
```

GetContent is:

```
function getContent(x){
  var xhr=null;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();}
  else if(window.ActiveXObject){xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  envoi = "formmail.php?agence="+$('#agence').val()+"&soc=<?php echo $_SESSION['SOC'] ?>";
  xhr.open("GET",envoi,false);
  xhr.send(null);
  obj=document.getElementById(x);
  obj.innerHTML =xhr.responseText;
}
```

This works pretty great.

But here is what's inside "formmail.php"

```
 <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mail 1</label>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="PMCPYMAIL1" id="inputEmail1" onkeyup="onkeyupmail(1,'')" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo getmail('PMCPYMAIL1')?>">
</div>
<input type="text" value="Envoyer mail de test" id="buttonmail1" onclick="onclickmail(1,'');" class="btn btn-default col-sm-2">
<input type="text" value="Effacer" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini col-sm-1" id="amail1" onclick="deletemail(1,'')" style="margin-left: 35px;">


<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
 <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('tada');
  pageLoad = function(){

    if ($('#inputEmail1' ).val() == ''){
      $('#buttonmail1').hide();
      $('#amail1').hide();
    }
  };
  pageLoad();

</script>
```

The script should hide the input text if the input email is empty. It works well when i load the page for the first time (the alert 'tada' shows) but not when it's call from the ajax call. Can you help me to find why please ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getContent(x){
  var xhr=null;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();}
  else if(window.ActiveXObject){xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  envoi = "formmail.php?agence="+$('#agence').val()+"&soc=<?php echo $_SESSION['SOC'] ?>";
  xhr.open("GET",envoi,false);
  xhr.send(null);
  obj=document.getElementById(x);

  if(xhr.responseText != ""){
      obj.innerHTML =xhr.responseText;
  }else{
      $('#buttonmail1').hide();
      $('#amail1').hide();
  }
}
```

--------------- new code block 1 -----------------

// use this to check your email input boxes for null values before sending to the server

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('form').click(function(){
                var emptyVals = [];
                $(".form-control").each(function(){
                    if($(this).val() == ""){
                        emptyVals.push($(this));
                    }
                });
                if(emptyVals.length > 0){
                    // don't send form one or more email values are empty
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

--------------- new code block 2 -----------------

// this would be the way I'd recommend sending the AJAX (using jQuery)

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function getContent(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"formmail.php",
                    data:"agence="+$('#agence').val()+"&soc=<?php echo $_SESSION['SOC'] ?>"
                }).done(function(data){
                    if(data!=""){
                        // checks to see if there is an empty string at the load of the content

                    }
                })
            }

        });
    </script>
```

--------------- new code block 3 -----------------

// hide all btns from the start (you can probably also deduce from this how to hide each individual element seperately)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".form-control").each(function(){
        $(this)
           .parent()
              .next("input.btn")
                 .hide()
                   .next("input.btn-danger")
                      .hide();
});
```

Comment: Each time the ajax call fires you should evaluate the response for the empty string, and hide the inputs accordingly.

Comment: okay i see, but i have 5 times the 3 inputs in fact. It's look like this http://puu.sh/6QSpJ.png how can i know which input is empty whith  xhr.responseText ?

Comment: can you provide an example of your response?

Comment: `console.log(xhr.responseText);`  give all the formmail.php content. Like that [link](http://puu.sh/6QT9X.png)

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but that looks like the page source, not the response text

Comment: Let's back up here Roadirsh, why would you want a round trip to the server to check for the empty string?  It's good to have it there too, but wouldn't you want a front-end solution to catch the problem before wasting a roundtrip to your server?  So for example, would you like me to help you write a front-end routine to check for empty values, and then only send the inputs that actually contain values filled in by the users?  Also, would you like an example of using jQuery to send the AJAX request - rather than writing it manually?

Comment: In fact i would like to check the server to get email adress according to the select option (and without having to refresh the entire page). and furthermore, i would like to check if there is an empty string à the load of the content. To show or not the button. But i accept an exemple of jquery and the Ajax request if possible thx^^ (And sorry for my english...)

Comment: Your English is great, I only know one language so I should be envious.  I will provide a few examples for you. ...

Comment: Thx a lot ! Everything works perfectly now :D And you are fluent in javascript, i am envious now :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using XMLHttpRequest manually instead of jQuery's $.Ajax() then you need to use "onreadystatechange":

```
var xhr = null;

function getContent(x){
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();}
  else if(window.ActiveXObject){xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  envoi = "formmail.php?agence="+$('#agence').val()+"&soc=<?php echo $_SESSION['SOC'] ?>";
  xhr.open("GET",envoi,false);
  xhr.send(null);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
}

function handleResponse() {
  var result;

  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr.responseText != "") {
      $('#' + x).html(xhr.responseText);
    }
    else {
      $('#buttonmail1').hide();
      $('#amail1').hide();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: okay i see, but i have 5 times the 3 inputs in fact. It's look like this http://puu.sh/6QSpJ.png how can i know which input is empty whith  xhr.responseText ?